# Taking a relative limit

Tags: limits

I am looking at Hamiltonians for specific physical situations. I have taken a given Hamiltonian $\vec{H}(\vec{p}, \vec{x})$ and have found the following Hamiltonian equations:
$$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = \frac{\vec{p}c^2}{\sqrt{m_0^2c^4 + |\vec{p}|^2c^2}}$$
and further that
$$\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt} = -V(\vec{x})$$
I am now instructed to take the limit $\|\vec{p}| << m_0c$. I have not come across this kind of limit notation in the past - what precisely does it mean?

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $ z \equiv \frac{|p|}{m_0 c}$ then the limit $|p|<< m_0 c $ means $z<<1$ so that we can  use the approximation $(1+z)^n \approx 1+nz$ and keep only the lowest powers of $z$ in any polynomial expansion.

note that $$ \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = \frac{\vec{p}c^2}{\sqrt{m_0^2c^4 + |\vec{p}|^2c^2}} = \frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z^2}} \hat p c \approx z(1-\frac{z^2}{2}) \hat p c \approx z \hat p c = \frac{\vec p}{m_0} $$

So we recover the non-relativistic result $ \vec p = m \vec v $

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer - how did you get the $\frac{z}{\sqrt{1 + z^2}}\hat{p}c$ expression? When I use your substitution it seems like there should be a $c^2$ on the top?

Comment: I divided numerator and denominator by $ m_0 c^2$ so the numerator becomes $\frac{ \vec p}{m_0} = \frac{|p|\hat p c}{m_0 c} = z c \hat p $